# Explanation for the orders of subgroups and number of groups with these orders.

Tags: group-theory

This was a question on my exam that was just given back and I need help understanding why both (a) and (b) and (c) are the answers they are.

In each group listed below, give the orders of the subgroups of the given group and how many different subgroups there are for each order.

(a) D5

There is 1 subgroup of order 1, 5 subgroups of order 2, 1 subgroup of order
5, and 1 subgroup of order 10.

(b) V4

There are 3 subgroups of order 2, one subgroup of order 1, and one subgroup of
order 4.

(c) $Z_{100}$

There is one subgroup of each of the following orders: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50,
100

Comment: What have you tried? For example $D_5$ has 10 elements, and is generated by $a$ and $b$, with $a^5=1=b^2$ and $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$. Can you write out all the elements of the group?

Comment: Well $D_5$ has 2*5 = 10 elements. 1 element is the identity element, say e. Then there are 9 other elements (of rotations (R) and reflections (V)). For a Pentagon (regular polygon with 5 sides) there is 4 rotations and 5 reflections. The group of rotations form a cyclic subgroup while the reflections have order 2.
Okay I understand (a) thus far.

Answer (score 2):

(a) $D_5$ has order $10$ and is generated by a rotation $r$ (the unique element of order $5$, spanning the *unique* subgroup of order $5$) and by a reflection $s$, which satisfies $s^2=1$, but also $s^{-1}r=r^{-1}s^{-1}$ This should tell that the elements of order $2$ are exactly $s,rs,r^2s,r^3s,r^4s$.

(b) I do not know the notation but it seems to be the Klein group $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. I'll leave it to you, it has only four elements.

(c) $\mathbb Z_{100}$ is cyclic. Its subgroups are cyclic as well. There is exactly one cyclic subgroup for each divisor of the order. (In general, there is exactly one cyclic group of order $n$, for each $n$).

**Added.**
If $n=|G|$ is the order of a cyclic group $G$, there is exactly one cyclic sugroup of order $m$ (up to isomorphism), for every divisor $m\,|\,n$. (The unicity is easy, because cyclic groups are unique up to isomorphism, for any order.) Indeed, if $u$ is a generator of $G$, then the element $u^{n/m}$ will have order $m$ in $G$. Thus it generates a subgroup $H\leq G$ of order $m$, unique up to isomorphism. Note that $u^{n/m}$ is not the possible generator of $H$, but any of the $\phi(n/m)$ generators produces an isomorphic copy of $H$.

Comment: So in general:
(a) $D_n$ has 2*n elements. It'll have 1 subgroup of order  1 (namely the group containing the identity).

It'll have n subgroups of order 2.

1 subgroup of order 10 (namely the group itself).

And 1 subgroup of order n?

Comment: For (b) the Klein 4 group is Isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 x \mathbb{Z}_2$ so (a,b) for a,b $\in$ \mathbb{Z}_2.
The subgroups would be 
{(0,0)}, {(1,0).(0,0)}, {(0,1),(0,0)}, {{1,1},(0,0)}, {(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)} I'd suppose.

Comment: (c) $Z_{100}$ 
100 = $1*2^2*5^2$ so there is 1 group of order 
$\frac{100}{1}$, $\frac{100}{2}$, $\frac{100}{2^2}$, $\frac{100}{5}$, $\frac{100}{5^2}$, $\frac{100}{2*5}$, 
$\frac{100}{2^2*5}$, ....?

Why is this?

Comment: Another QUESTION since we're talking about cyclic subgroups. 

Suppose G is a group, g $\in$ G, and|g| = 10000, then what is 
$|g^{90}|$?

Comment: I added a last paragraph. But I encourage you to ask another separate question if you have other doubts :)

Comment: No. If $n$ is even, for $D_n$ there are $2n$ subgroups of order 2 (reflect through opposed vertices or through midpoints between vertices). Also one subgroup for each divisor of $n$ (like the $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ case).

Comment: You are right, I deleted my previous comment.